# How to generate vcproj files?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010, visual-c++-2008

Suppose I've got a cross-platform C++ library, let's call it ylib. My primary development platform is Linux. I'd like ylib to be buildable by MSVC (2008, 2010, 11, etc).

What's the best way to do this? Do I generate .vcproj files? If so, how? Ideally I'd be able to generate them without using Windows myself. No extra dependencies should be required for Windows.
Multiple variants should be build: debug dll, debug lib, release dll, release lib with dynamic runtime and release lib with static runtime.

Comment: What about installing Visual Studio and creating a project from there, then adding your stuff in?

Comment: How do you know that it builds correctly on Windows if you haven't tried compiling it there?

Comment: @Roman: *Ideally I'd be able to generate them without using Windows myself.*

Comment: @bo: Somebody else tried

Answer (score 5):

You could use [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/) for your build scripts.  Cmake has the ability to generate visual studio project files from the cmake build scripts.  So you'd just need to distribute your cmake files, then individual people using windows could generate MSVC project files from that.

Though as pointed out in the comments, it'd be difficult to guarantee that you could actually build your project under visual studio without trying it out yourself.

EDIT: Though I've just realized that you requested no extra dependencies on linux, which this would not solve.  Unless you generated the vcproj files yourself using cmake, and distributed them.  But personally I think it'd be better to just have the cmake dependency.  It's freely available, and easy to install.

This also has the advantage of supporting whatever version of visual studio your end user happens to have, without the need for distributing several different formats.

Comment: +1 CMake works fine for this, but it kind of makes you want to stab your eyes out everytime you edit the CMake scripts. Also, beware that the generated VS project files require CMake as well.

Comment: @villintehaspam: By experience, I can tell you that using autotools and its multiple syntaxes is much more self-stab-inducing than cmake, which reunites all build steps in one file/language which is rather easy to program with :)

Comment: @obmarg: You can't distribute cmake generated vcproj files. Ensuring all variants are build (and have proper output names) is also non-trivial with cmake.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to understand the format of vcproj files and then write them - they are simply XML.

I don't know how well MSFT document the settings (not very if history is a guide) - so for simple projects I would just create a project in MSVC and look at what it writes.

Alternatively you could just use [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/) which already does this.

Comment: It's 2012. I was hoping writing such files by hand wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @XTF - I'm sure that with a big enough licence payment and a non-disclosure agreement MSFT will give you the spec for the XML. Or you could read the cmake sources